# Stringbuilder adds backslash after converting it to string

Tags: c#, string, stringbuilder

I have a situation in which I want to add inverted commas the the string.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int valueCounter = 0;
        int valueCount = 0;
        var valueBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        List<string> values = new List<string>();
        values.Add("AAAA");
        values.Add("BBBB");
        values.Add("CCCC");
        valueCount = values.Count;

        foreach (var value in values)
        {
            valueCounter++;
            if ((valueCounter - 1) > 0)
                valueBuilder.Append("\"");
            valueBuilder.Append(values[valueCounter - 1].ToString());

            if (valueCounter != valueCount)
            {
                valueBuilder.Append(@",");
            }
        }

        string output = valueBuilder.ToString();

    }
```

[image]
[image]

As you can see, after converting the Stringbuilder to string, it adds the backslash to the string.

Please help me to know how I can get the desired out as : "AAAA","BBBB", "CCCC"

Comment: The backslash isn't part of the string, it's just how the tool you're using is displaying it.

Comment: Why don't you remove the line which adds the '\' character?: valueBuilder.Append("\"");

Comment: If you were to perform a `System.out.println(output);` you would not see the backslash.

Comment: Are you looking at this in the debugger, by any chance?

Comment: Yes, I am looking it into the debugger.

Comment: @JRSofty You mean `Console.WriteLine(output)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are the corrected version of your code (fixed enclosing of the first fragments):

```
string[] strArr = new string[] { 
    "AAAA", "BBBB","CCCC"
};
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(int i = 0; i < strArr.Length; i++) {
    sb.Append('"');
    sb.Append(strArr[i]);
    sb.Append('"');
    if(i < strArr.Length - 1)
        sb.Append(',');
}
var output = sb.ToString();
```

This is how the debugger displays result (quoted/escaped view):
[image]

This is how it looks in human-readable format:
`"AAAA","BBBB","CCCC"`

**Tips&tricks:**
You can use the `nq` [format-specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e514eeby(v=VS.100).aspx) to display string unquoted/unescaped:

```
    output,nq
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the following code for `foreach` loop will solve your problem.

```
foreach (var value in values)
    {
        value = "\""+value+"\"";
        valueBuilder.Append(value);

        if (++valueCounter != valueCount)
        {
            valueBuilder.Append(@",");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

The use of quotation marks in a Java String object must be escaped. The `\` you are complaining about is only visible in your tool and is required to escape the `"` so that no error occurs. If you were to perform a `System.out.println(output);` you will not see the `\` character.

Answer (score -2):

Just remove `valueBuilder.Append("\"");`

My mistake. It does just escape the `\`

Comment: That doesn't add a backslash. It just adds a double quote.

Comment: That would cause an error. The \ is needed to escape the ".